# Diferencia entre Execute y Query en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Cuando ejecuto una consulta en la base de datos MySQL el comando **Execute** congela completamente la base de datos, mientras que si el comando es **Query** corre normalmente la consulta. ¿Cuál es la diferente entre estos dos comandos?

Comment: si te ha servido alguna respuesta, te recomiendo que la marques como respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buenos dias, te responderé de manera general usando MySQLi y PDO, ya que no especificas el tipo de clase de consulta:

---

```
query()
```

Ejecuta una consulta estandarizada SQL a la base de datos, esto requiere escapar correctamente los datos para evitar inyecciones sql (vease: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)), generalmente se usa cuando obtendrás datos sin ninguna condición o característica, es decir sin usar `WHERE`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
$sql = 'SELECT nombre, color, calorias FROM frutas ORDER BY nombre';
    foreach ($conexion->query($sql) as $valor) {
        echo $valor['nombre'] . "\t";
        echo $valor['color'] . "\t";
        echo $valor['calorias'] . "\n";
    }
```

Como se aprecia en el ejemplo únicamente devolvemos datos directos, es decir, no buscamos usar `WHERE` para condicionar los resultados, en el caso de querer hacerlo debemos asignar parámetros, para eso se usa el `execute`, ya que este acompaña a las `sentencias preparadas`(vease: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Otro problema del `query()`, es que debes declarar la sentencia de nuevo para volver a usar la consulta.

Haciendo las consultas menos eficientes.

---

```
execute()
```

Corre o ejecuta una `sentencia preparada` que permite asignar parámetros que evitan la inyección SQL ya que no debes recurrir a comillas o escapar caracteres, en el caso de que quieras ejecutar de nuevo la consulta a la base de datos, basta con ejecutar `execute` de nuevo para hacerlo.

Esto requiere ademas que la sentencia se `prepare` antes.

**Ejemplo:**

```
$consulta = $conexion->prepare('SELECT nombre, color, calorias FROM frutas
    WHERE calorias < :calorias AND color = :color');
$consulta->bindValue(':calorias', $calorias);
$consulta->bindValue('color', $color);
$consulta->execute();
```

**Donde:**

```
 $consulta->bindValue('calorias', $calorias) -> Asignar parametros
```

Le asignamos $calorias al parametro calorias , el cual corresponde al campo calorias de la tabla frutas.

Como observas en la sentencia SQL cuando igualamos calorias=:calorias, se presentan dos puntos, eso representa que :calorias es una cajita donde se metera luego el valor de la variable asignada.

Esto porque las sentencias preparadas primero mandan a MySQL la sentencia:

```
SELECT nombre, color, calorias FROM frutas
        WHERE calorias < :calorias AND color = :color
```

Y luego le mandan los valores

```
:color, $color
```

Para que al darle execute ambas se combinen algo asi:

```
SELECT nombre, color, calorias FROM frutas
        WHERE calorias < $calorias AND color=$color
```

Pero todo ocurre dentro del mismo MySQL, no en el PHP.

**En conclusion:**

`query():` consultas simples sin condicionales (inseguro si no se sabe estructrar la consulta SQL).

`execute():` consultas con parámetros pasados por asignación (mas seguras, si se emplea PDO o MySQLi permiten definir el tipo de dato que recibirán)

---

> el comando Execute congela completamente la base de datos

Ahora, que hacemos con esto, necesitaria que publicaras la consulta para ver que error podria presentar.

---

Para saber mas sobre inyeccion sql y sentencias preparadas te invito a leer:

https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

https://phpdelusions.net/safemysql

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work/332367#332367

[¿Qué es la inyección SQL y cómo puedo evitarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518/qu%C3%A9-es-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-y-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-evitarla)

[¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Answer (score 2):

**Query** ejecuta una instrucción SQL estándar y puede provocar Inyecciones SQL y otros problemas.

**Execute** ejecuta una instrucción preparada que le permite enlazar parámetros para evitar la necesidad de escapar o citar los parámetros. También funcionará mejor si está repitiendo una consulta varias veces.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour);
$sth->execute();
```

En resumen, Execute, de cierta forma es más seguro. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Me gustaría aportar **otras** diferencias entre `query` y `execute`, tomando en cuenta las API PDO y MySQLi, que son actualmente las dos recomendadas por PHP para manejar los datos de forma segura. Ya que la extensión `mysql_*` es insegura y por tanto obsoleta.

---

### query

Realiza una consulta a la base de datos y la puedes usar sin peligro cuando en la misma no haya valores que sean obtenidos desde fuera.

Hay una pequeña diferencia con respecto a `query` en cuanto los valores devueltos si usas PDO o MySQLi.

- **Valores devueltos en PDO**

> [PDO::query()](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.query.php) devuelve un objeto [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/es/class.pdostatement.php), o `FALSE` en
>   caso de error.

- **Valores devueltos en MySQLi**

> [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) Retorna `FALSE` en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo SELECT, SHOW,
>   DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN es exitosa, `mysqli_query()` retornará un objeto
>   mysqli_result. **Para otras consultas exitosas de `mysqli_query()`
>   retornará TRUE**. O sea, no devuelve conjunto de resultados en todos
>   los tipos de consultas.

---

### execute

Prepara una sentencia SQL para su ejecución.

**También hay diferencias** si trabajas con PDO o con MySQLi:

- **Usando PDO**

[PDO::exec()](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.exec.php) ejecuta una sentencia SQL en una única llamada a la función, devolviendo el número de filas afectadas por la sentencia.

PDO::exec() no devuelve resultados de una sentencia SELECT. Para una sentencia SELECT que sólo se necesita ejecutar una vez en el programa, se debe considerar el uso de PDO::query(). Para una sentencia que se deba ejecutar en múltiples ocasiones, preparar un objeto PDOStatement con PDO::prepare() y ejecutarlo con PDOStatement::execute().

**valores devueltos**

PDO::exec() devuelve el número de filas modificadas o borradas por la sentencia SQL ejecutada. Si no hay filas afectadas, PDO::exec() devuelve 0.

Nota importante:

Dado que execute se usa con consultas preparadas, es importante señalar lo siguiente:

> PDO **emulará sentencias preparadas/parámetros de sustitución para
>   drivers que no lo soporten nativamente**, y puede reescribir el estilo
>   de los parámetros de sustitución por una forma más apropiada, si el
>   driver soporta un estilo pero no el otro.

Esto puede resultar peligroso de cara a la Inyección SQL. Por eso, siempre que usemos PDO debemos establecer al modo `off` la emulación de consultas preparadas. Para más detalles se pueden ver **[esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967)** la pregunta: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)

---

- **Usando MySQLi**

[mysqli_stmt::execute](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) Ejecuta una consulta que ha sido previamente preparada usando la función mysqli_prepare(). Cuando se ejecutó cualquier marcador de parámetro que existe, será automáticamente reemplazado con los datos apropiados.

Si la sentencia es UPDATE, DELETE, o INSERT, se puede determinar el número total de filas afectadas usando le función mysqli_stmt_affected_rows(). Asimismo, si la consulta produce un conjunto de resultados se usa la función mysqli_stmt_fetch().

Al usar mysqli_stmt_execute(), se debe usar la función mysqli_stmt_fetch() para obtener los datos antes de realizar cualquier consulta adicional.

**valores devueltos**

`mysqli_prepare()` devuelve un objeto de sentencia o FALSE si ocurre un error. A diferencia de PDO, no hace saltar excepciones.

Comment: Excelente aporte